# SCRAPY: how to store data into Mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem with scrapy, while attempting to store data into a mysql database: I get the following error: [(screenshot here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/28yzeegalyxidof/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-09-28%2018.48.18.png?dl=0)

My code in pipelines.py is

```
class SQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('localhost', db='python',
                user='root', passwd='', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # run db query in thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)

        return item

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
        # create record if doesn't exist. 
        # all this block run on it's own thread
        tx.execute("select * from test where name = %s", (item['name'][0], ))
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            tx.execute(\
                "insert into test (name, price) "
                "values (%s, %s)",
                (item['link'][0],
                 datetime.datetime.now())
            )
            log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

(I took it from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/66986/mysql-pipeline/)).

And my parsing class is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = DmozItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content').extract()[0]
    item['price'] = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

I know that this question has already been asked, but I tried all the different answer before asking here, and none of them works...

Does someone can please help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to your screenshot you have an indentation problem. Check your spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Actually @alecxe was right, and his remarks led me to the solution.

MySQLdb was simply not installed, and the reason is that its installation failed because I have an accent in my name and that Python could not handle the path because of this.

Once again, thank you very much @alecxe !

Answer (score 0):

Read the error carefully - it says `IndentationError` on the following line:

```
yield item
```

This means you need to check your indentation to be consistent (4 spaces per indent):

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = DmozItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content').extract()[0]
    item['price'] = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

And don't mix tab and spaces if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I fixed it, but unfortunatly this was not the main problem, because when I remove pipelines.py, the crawler is working. 
This is the pipeline that is not working and I really do not understand why...

Comment: @galopin okay, what error(s) are you getting now? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe! I got these errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct4q5zzqzbsbfn6/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-09-28%2019.23.28.png?dl=0

Comment: @galopin okay, this might be because of multiple things. Could you please make gists of your current complete `pipelines.py` and `settings.py` (https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/537d10edd821e7bef92a ! Thanks a lot, again

Comment: @galopin what if you would remove all imports except `import MySQLdb` from the pipeline? Also, what happens if you `import MySQLdb` in the python console? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I get more errors ^^
If I remove everything except "import MYSQLdb" in pipelines.py I get exactly the same error, but if I add "import MYSQLdb" to the python console, I get a lot of errors

Comment: @galopin so, yeah, this sounds like our problem is that `MySQLdb` cannot be imported. What errors do you get if you `import MySQLdb` on the console?